# grep doesn't work as I think

Tags: grep

I want to check if `parsoid` service is running. So I run this command:

```
service --status-all|grep 'parsoid'
```

But the result is:

```
 [ ? ]  aliyun-rdate

 [ ? ]  console-setup

 [ ? ]  dns-clean

 [ ? ]  irqbalance

 [ ? ]  killprocs

 [ ? ]  kmod

 [ ? ]  mysql

 [ ? ]  networking

 [ ? ]  ondemand

 [ ? ]  pppd-dns

 [ ? ]  rc.local

 [ ? ]  sendsigs

 [ ? ]  umountfs

 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh

 [ ? ]  umountroot
```

Why? shouldn't  grep be able to speak parsoid screened out of it?

Comment: Perhaps `service --status-all` writes to stderr as well ? Can you try `service --status-all 2>&1 | grep 'parsoid' `

Comment: If you want the status of a specific service then ask `service` for the status of that service instead of asking for the status of every service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
service --status-all 2>&1|grep -o 'parsoid'
```

`1` is stdout and `2` is stderr.

`>` is for redirection

`&` specifies that what follows is a file descriptor (not a filename)

`2>&1` redirects  `stderr` to `stdout` and then the `stdout` is piped into the `grep`

Note: `service --status-all` writes to `stderr`.

Comment: I'd drop an explanation of `2>&1` into your answer too for those discovering this later. Or just refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21